# Jfrog Artifactory Highly Available Setup in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, artifactory, high-availability

We are planning to setup Artifactory Highly Available Setup in Kubernetes.
One should be primary and other should be secondary, both sharing the same database. There should be automatic fail over to secondary if the primary is not available.

Please share your recommendations if you have implemented this kind of HA setup in kubernetes.

Comment: This question is a bit generic and too high level - it would be good to add what you investigated and add some details to it and be more specific.

Comment: Are you asking about secondary node should take over responsibilities of the primary node like replication, GC etc?

Comment: Replication is not required. Both primary and secondary share same database.

Answer (score 0):

I believe an active-active setting is on the roadmap. The failover feature may be important for some architecture but it is less important for artifactory HA running in k8s. The primary node pod will be rescheduled by k8s if it is down. It only takes a few mins for the primary to comes back again. HA cluster can keep functioning even if the primary node is down. You can find a list of jobs that will be impacted when primary node is down [here](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/what-are-the-tasks-effected-when-there-is-a-failure-of-the-primary-node/). You may also choose not to include the primary node in load balancer so that it doesn't serve traffic when you deploy HA on k8s.